# Angular + node.js, setting the image static path (relative path)

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb

I'm wanting to set the static path with node.js in `app.js`.

Such as the follow with setting in the `public` folder:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

When I use template engines, such as `mustache` `https://mustache.github.io/`，
you can set it using a relative path in the template to get a photo `a.jpg`, like:

```
<img src="./a.jpg">
```

When I save a user's photo in the `public` folder.

In Angular, how do I set the img url relative path from the node.js server folder.

If I save the the full URL in the `DB` and set the URL in `img`:

```
    http://120.8.12.8:3000/a.jpg
    //or
    http://domainname:3000/a.jpg
```

html:

```
<img src="http://120.8.12.8:3000/a.jpg">
<img src="http://domainname:3000/a.jpg">
```

When I change the IP or domain name, the URL will fail.
How can I set it?

Comment: Can you move domain to a environment variable of an angular app?

Comment: where is your angular app running, which port? Have you configured a server for both Node and Angular

Comment: angular 4200 port, node.js 3000 port, how to set that config for both? only set node.js config? if I want set relative path to connect node.js static path.

Comment: @Albert, Can you please share, how did you fixed it ?

Answer (score 0):

I would not save the full path in the database.
Otherwise, I will save information about how to generate the path.
You can have 2 fields in the database, like:

```
{
"relativePath" : "a.jpg",
"server" : "http://120.8.12.8:3000"
}
```

After this, and assuming you are consuming the resource from angular, you have several options:

1. You can directly mix the relativePath and the server in the frontend and create the URL to place in the link
2. You can hardcode in your angular app what is the "server", and mix that with the relativePath. In this case, in case you migrate the images you just need to modify the frontend
3. (The best for me). Create an endpoint in the server which gives you what is the host of the image server, call it from your angular app and then create the full link with this response and the relative image path.

Comment: mean like this:`[src] = "server + relativePath"`, but I don't want to assemble URL, this is not convenient to manage variables.